# AWS Lambda Ruby - Environment variables are not available

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to send secrets to my Ruby Lambda function but the `ENV` variable does not seem to contain my AWS secrets. What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

In the logs there are no trace at all of my 'SECRET' variable in ENV

(Even when I disable encryption, no trace of the ENV variable, and when I try to use the "code" provided by AWS for decryption, it just timeouts after 3secs)

Answer (score 0):

Try with env (in lower case), and remove ENV.keys.